# Long Range Motion Detection solutions

Tags: sensor, motion, pir

I'm trying to find solutions for the security of an outdoor area (2km long and 1km wide). We want to detect any breach through the borders of the area, if someone sneaks in and/or someone goes out.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the least detection nodes possible on the borders that use solar power packs to take their juice from. Let's assume that we can have 5-10 nodes in 2km length (max of 1 node each 200m) and 5 nodes in 1km width of the area. We'll have a gateway that receives the data from these end devices once motion is detected through RF (and that's not a problem). These motion sensors should be able to detect movement up to 200m away (until the next node), only detect human movements (not pets, cars, etc.), work with arduino or RPi and don't be in need of too much power.

I've done some research already, but I thought maybe someone could introduce me to an specific sensor or solution.

Comment: Is a thermal camera in budget?

Comment: sure, arduino can do everything. You are talking about the system complexity that even border patrol doesn't have it and you wish to solve with an arduino and 10 bucks.

Comment: There are many ways to detect such things.  All have their own strengths and weaknesses.  There is no perfect system  - and certainly no "cheap, low power, only detect people" system.  You will always have to deal with false positives (small animal triggers your alarm instead of a person) and false negatives (person sneaks through without being detected.) The more you can put up in the way of detectors (of different types) and processing (to combine the sensor readings to filter out the bad results) the better it will be.

Comment: *motion is detected through RF (and that's not a problem).* I Agree *These motion sensors should be able to detect movement up to 200m away* That's not going to happen with cheap RF sensors *only detect human movements (not pets, cars, etc.)* That's only possible in SciFi movies !

Comment: I used this once http://www.cryptomuseum.com/radar/zb298/index.htm

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie The data from this detector are sent through RF, the detector itself has to be determined yet.

Comment: Have you considered landmines?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Indeed, I misunderstood. I was thinking Radar sensors. Those are a possible solution but expensive.

Comment: Ask Donald Trump - he's planning on building a big wall to keep folk out.

Comment: @Jeroen3 I'm looking for  motion detectors actually :)

Comment: @GregoryKornblum :D

Comment: @DirkBruere I see. You know the problem with these kind of sensors (dopplers I mean) is that behind the area we want to separate is a road that has fairly active traffic, so we're looking for solutions that only watch for the activity on or inside the border not outside of it, I think doppler motion sensors don't do that, correct me if I'm wrong :)
But I appreciate it.

Comment: this problem is interesting due the unheardly astounding requirements. Is the border some physical obstacle or only a line on the map? Can any optical rays propagate along the border or are there stones, high grass, bushes, trees etc? Is it essential to supervise all of the area or the border only? What about the air flank and the underground? Ways to infiltrate underwater?

Comment: @user287001 There's no obstacle and we only want to monitor the line or border. Consider it a desert.

Comment: I once worked on such project. Very easy if you don't care about money. But to make it commercially viable it takes a very serious system engineering and investments.